# using a cursor in a trigger

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write a trigger function that executes when an insert is performed. The condition is, if the id already exists then the time_create should now be the time_dead.

```
 CREATE function archive_temp() returns trigger as '
 begin
   insert into  temporary_archive
  values
 (
 OLD.id,
   OLD.time_create,
   OLD.time_dead,
    OLD.fname,
    current_user,
    now(),
      now(),
  TG_OP
    );
     return null;
    end;
   ' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
     -----------------------------

CREATE TRIGGER archive_temps 
AFTER DELETE OR UPDATE 
on temporary_object
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
temporary_archive temporary_object.id%type;
begin
if inserting then 
select id into temporary_archive
from temporary_object
where id = :old.id;
if temporary_archive is not null then

 EXECUTE PROCEDURE archive_temps();
 end if;
 end if;ins
```

Comment: how can i do it? that code is as far as i could go

Comment: doesn't anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me from your example like you are trying to do things the Oracle way.  PostgreSQL is different.  I also do not see any uses of cursors anywhere in your code so the question may be misleading.

In PostgreSQL, triggers can only call procedures and the procedures must be largely self-contained.  In essence you are going to have to refactor your code a bit.  The only accepted syntax after `FOR EACH ROW` is `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` and so your other logic will have to be moved into user defined functions.  You could, if you want, apply the function in a `WHEN` condition by calling the function (if your function returns bool).  Or you could build it into your trigger logic.